# Error with Numba compilation source elided error

Tags: python, numpy, numba

Goodmorning,

I am decently new with Numba.
I am testing a function that:

- make a subset of a numpy array
- calculate the average over axis 0

Everything is in numpy and it works (to test just comment out jit decorator).

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def from_node_to_centroid(npCoor,nodeList):
    """[summary]

    Calculate centroids
    """
    elem = npCoor[np.isin(npCoor[:,0],nodeList)]
    print(elem[:,1:])  # <--- I want to average x,y,z so I exclude the first column
    meanData =  np.apply_along_axis(np.mean,1,elem[:,1:])
        
    return meanData


# Array with coordinates
# npCoor format: index, x_value, y_value_z_value
npCoor=np.array([
                [1,4,5,6],
                [2,1,5,5],
                [3,2,4,4]
                ])

# nodes for which I want the average of x,y,z
nodeList=[1,2]


mean=from_node_to_centroid(npCoor,nodeList)

print(mean)
```

If I add the jit decorator, I get an error

```
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.isin' or unsupported use of the function.

File "../python_test.py", line 10:
def from_node_to_centroid(npCoor,nodeList):
    <source elided>
        """
        elem = npCoor[np.isin(npCoor[:,0],nodeList)]
 ^

During: typing of get attribute at .../python_test.py (10)

File "../python_test.py", line 10:
def from_node_to_centroid(npCoor,nodeList):
    <source elided>
        """
        elem = npCoor[np.isin(npCoor[:,0],nodeList)]
 ^
```

Thanks to whom help me

Comment: Is there more traceback than just this? The caret indicates it's a syntax error, but we're missing part of the error message.

Comment: Don't use images for code or error messages. Just copy-paste the traceback, and format it as a code block.

Comment: No...I have no other message...you can run all the code...the full code is what is posted...it works if you comment the jit decorator

Comment: I get a different error message: "Use of unsupported NumPy function 'numpy.isin' or unsupported use of the function.". Perhaps I'm overlooking something. This is for Python 3.9, Numba 0.54 and NumPy 1.20.

Comment: See also https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html .

Comment: Given that you're using Numba, it may make sense to simply implement the `isin` part in a for loop.